# How to track a file to know where it has gone

Tags: script, file-permissions, tracking

How do you make a file trackable. Like for a vehicle we can keep a gps tracker, and it kind of gives you report saying its moving and has gone to these locations.

Similarly if I could have a tracker for a file, one would be able to find out if the file he has shared is being misused or not right?

So I have an assumption these will be treated as a virus. Will it?

One of the things I can think of is that, if the file is opened, a script is run to either report it. Is it possible to know if the file has been replicated as well?
or deleted? How does one make this possible and at the same time not under a virus tag.

Comment: The script or macro can be disabledby the user during the opening process

Comment: I can't see this being possible with current technology except under very restricted circumstances which you have no control over. And I hope it never is. It would provide many opportunities for malicious use.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.  A file is nothing more than 1s and 0s and cannot *do* anything.  Technically, a *program* could do this under some circumstances, but it would have to be executed, not read, and therefore not be considered a "file."